# How to increase the speed of the page loading in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

I am .net programmer using Asp.net ,C#  and Sql server 2005 to display set of information. My project is to create tools for Call Center Systems in my office.
Now i am have created the project. but its too slow and takes much time in the time of page loading and post back.

I need Suggestions to improve page performances and wat technologies can be used to make the tool efficient...

Answer (score 5):

First things first is to find out where the bottleneck is.  In a large application, my experience is that the bottleneck is never where you actually guess it is.  To do this, you want to use a performance profiler.  Visual Studio 2010 Premium includes a profiler.  But, I have had better success using third party profilers such as [ANTS Performance Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) from Redgate.  I've also heard good things about [DotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) from JetBrains, but I have not used that one personally.

Once you have found the bottleneck, you can start to look at ways to make that code faster.  You can ask more specific questions on SO if you need help once you find the specific problem.

Comment: yeah I found it.... Between Pages and Postbacks ... now i m using AJAX to make it faster to load......

Comment: there is a LOT happening between pages and postbacks.  AJAX will help if the issue is the amount of HTML being passed back and forth on a postback.  but it won't help if you are doing a lot of work on the server side to generate the output, for example.  be careful with assumptions when dealing with performance - they are almost always wrong in my experience.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use firefox, I would suggest trying the addon [YSlow](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yslow/). It gives suggestions to speed up pages and rates the page based on these suggestions. These rules are mainly from [Steve Souders](http://stevesouders.com/) which, I believe, are good for increasing page load speed.

Comment: thank u i will try this to check the Page load process...... Thank u again For Ur reply...

Answer (score 0):

You have to reduce the amount of work and information being posted back with each click. One manner of doing this is to remove everything from the ViewState that doesn't absolutely need to be there. By cutting down on the size of the ViewState, you can reduce the amount of information that must travel across the connection with each click. The next thing you can do to help ease the pain of loading is to start carving up your actions into smaller chunks and applying an AJAX solution. By using AJAX, you are sending less across the network and for longer processes you can fill the gaps with more useful progress bars. AJAX also ensures that only the action being requested is actually occurring so this cuts down on the amount of work the server has to do. AJAX is a fair amount of effort to accomplish for a complicated site. Third, reduce the amount of actual work being done by the page to produce the html. If you have static areas of the site or areas that can be made static, do it. If you can find a way to produce an output without the server having to crank it out, the faster everything will be.

Comment: Thanks for ur suggestion.. Now i m using AJAX to avoid postback...... Page performance improved well.......